# Zap the [advice] "meta-tag"

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, meta-tags

Seriously, there's 403 questions tagged `[advice]` [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/advice), 79 SU, 24 SF.  It must be a contender for the most useless tag ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree. The very picture of a [meta tag](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) ..

> How can you tell you’re using a meta-tag? It’s easier than you might think.
>
> 1. **If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag.** Every tag you use should be able to work, more or less, as the only tag on a question. Meta-tags, like [beginner], [subjective], and [best-practices], are useless by themselves — they tell you nothing at all about the content of the question.
> 2. **If the tag commonly means different things to different people, it’s probably a meta-tag.** In a cruel, ironic twist, the meaning of the tag [subjective] itself … is actually subjective. Ditto for [best-practices] and [beginner]. Best practices to whom? Beginner by what criteria? These tags are impossible to define by anything remotely resembling an objective metric. In comparison, the the meaning of tags like [java], [c#], and [javascript] are crystal clear to all but the nuttiest of nutbags.

... [burninating](http://www.homestarrunner.com/trogdor.html) it now.

Comment: Bah, I got sworded :-(

Comment: while I agree [advice] is a poor tag, why not just make it so meta-tags can only be added after one or more tags are added?  that way you can have the best of both worlds.  meta-tags are not useless.