# Account tab redirects to Area51 with "framing not allowed" error

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, profile-page, linked-accounts

I had an electronic gadgets account. Now, when I click on my associated accounts tab, I'm redirected to it's [Area 51 site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/614/electronic-gadgets) with a "no framing allowed".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I burninated it.

Comment: thanks. seems you're on a [burninating spree](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64708/zap-the-advice-meta-tag/64710#64710) :p